# Model associations in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to understand how rails works in respect to foreign key and primary keys. Coming from a pure SQL background the Rails method seems very alien to me.
I have the following two migrations:

Groups

```
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :city
      t.integer :event_id
      t.string :zip
      t.string :group_id
      t.text :topics
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :groups
  end
end
```

and Events:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :events do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :description
      t.string :city
      t.string :address
      t.time :time_t
      t.date :date_t
      t.string :group_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :events
  end
end
```

A Group can have many events and an event can belong to a single group. I have the following two models:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :group, :foreign_key => 'group_id'

end
```

and

```
 class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :title, :description, :city, :zip, :group_id, :topics
 has_many :events
end
```

not sure how to specify foreign keys and primary keys to this. For example a group is identified by the :group_id column and using that I need to fetch events that belong to a single group!
how do i do this!

Comment: You don't need to explicitly state the `foreign_key` name on a `belongs_to` if it is of the form you have (`associationname_id`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have group_id and event_id as strings in your migration, so I think you might be missing a rails convention.   The rails convention is that all tables have a primary key named id of type integer,  and any foreign keys reference it by the name of the model, singular, + _id:

```
table groups:
   id:  integer
   name:   string


table events:
   id:  integer
   name:  string
   group_id:  integer
```

From this convention, all you have to specify in your models is:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end
```

At this point, rails knows what to do by convention over configuration:  To find an event's group, it knows to look for  group_id (singular) to refer to groups.id (plural table name)

```
event = Event.first  #=> returns the first event in database
group = event.group  #=> returns the group object
```

Similarly, it know how to find all the events in a group

```
group = Group.first  #=> returns first group in database
group.events         #=> returns an Enumerable of all the events
```

For more reading, read the [rails guide on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: thnx DGM, I would still need to add events to a group based on the groups id which need to be a string... so I have groups like this: group A - group_id: "music", group B - group_id: "technology" and then I would need add events to these groups based on their group_id

Comment: You would need to search for the group that has the name you want, and then use it to create events.   For example,  `Group.where(:title => 'music').first << Event.new(event_attributes)`

Comment: isn't there any way to do exactly this through associations... without having to rely on .where ? possibly through a foreign key!?

Comment: it's not a number in my case... in my code there..i'm trying to make the group_id in CreateEvents a foreign key and the group_id in the CreateGroups a primary key and then when I create an event with the same group_id as a group's group_id... then that group will implicitly have that event without having to use .where !#

Comment: You're being more clever with your sql then the rails convention.  In the rails philosophy of convention over configuration,  it really pays to not fight it.   I see what you are doing with the sql, but I don't know if the effort to make it work in rails outweighs the cost of an extra query.  You've probably spent more time trying to figure out how to do it clever than the grand sum of all the queries this will ever generate! :D